# Download file time out

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, marionette

I use node.js and marionette.

I try to download big file to the browser.

I have in my html `<a>` tag with `href` to node.js function, which send zip file to the browser.

When the file is very big, the file downloaded ,before the server finished to prepare the file.

So,when I try to unzip the file I get an error.

I think it because time out.

In Ajax I know to set time out,but I cant use ajax to download file.

Where can I set time out to this request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you generate your zip file server sided at the same time? I dont think, thats a client sided timeout.

Update:
is that an upload? Then there are many limits which can be.

Comment: Yes.I generate my zip file in the server at the same time.

Comment: Then its a typical server sided timeout. Which language and webserver do you use? Apache2 + PHP?

Comment: I use node.js but we really decide to prepare the file earlier. thank you very much!